# Xcode automatically cancelled custom script added in the build phase of a project

Tags: ios, xcode, sh

I am trying to run custom script which I can run manually on the command line but I want that script to be run on xcode when I build the project for **Any iOS device** Target.
I don't specify any input or output files on this cause I don't have any requirements for that. It will run for some seconds and then Xcode automatically cancels it. Can anyone guide me on this?
Thanks in advance.
[Please see attached image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDxYY.png)
*Note - Script takes 10-15 minutes of time to complete, Could this be an issue, causing the cancelation of the script?*

It should run uninterrupted.

Comment: What is the relevant output in Xcode's build log?

Comment: It doesn't give any output, just says build canceled. and stopped my script directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was auto-incrementing the build number inside my script file to my .xcodeproj file. due to that Xcode is canceling my script.

Comment: Did you try to move this script to the top of build steps? Just wondering if Xcode would cancel the build in this case.

Comment: Yes It did cancel the build because I had written that on top of the Script.